# Re-processing pickles

Tags: pickling

I'm all set to make pickles (intending to hot-water can them for shelf-stable pickles) and I realize I don't have any more jars, so I'm making the brine and putting the whole batch in the fridge. I plan to buy more jars and do the processing next weekend. When I do this, should I make fresh brine so I can boil it before adding the pickles? Or can I heat the whole thing as-is before processing?

Process according to the recipe:

1. Salt cucumbers to dehydrate
2. Heat vinegar, add sugar to dissolve, add seasonings
3. Boil mixture
4. Add cucumbers, heat until heated through
5. Jar and process

What I did:

1. Salt cucumbers to dehydrate
2. Heat vinegar, add sugar to dissolve, add seasonings
3. Combine cucumbers and brine. Refridgerate

What I plan to do once I have jars:

1. Heat brine (with or without cucumbers?)
2. Jar and process

Comment: Rather than heat the pickles, I think your better alternative would be to strain the pickles into a pot, boil that, then pour it back over the pickles.  (so you don't end up over-cooking the items being pickled)

Comment: @Joe I added the steps the recipe wanted me to take, it had me heat the cucumbers but I have not thus far

Comment: Are these whole pickles or pieces (chips/spears)?  If whole, what type... kirby's (thin skin, not waxed)?

I make refrigerator pickles once every month or so.  I usually add the hot brine, screw on the lid, and let set until almost room temp - then put in the fridge. 

They may just turn out ok after sitting two or three days longer than you'd normally let them before eating.

Comment: Slices of... Pickling cucumbers? They're from my CSA box.

Comment: Reheating/simmering after adding the slices to the brine will make the pickling cucumbers (kirby's I'm guessing) a bit softer.  I do this with bread and butter pickles. I don't simmer for dill, which (in my experience) results in a crisper product. That said, the dills need to sit longer in the brine.

I still think that your pickles will turn out ok, albeit a bit crisper (they also need to sit for a couple days longer).  

Absent the jarring and processing (step 4 and 5), the shelf life may be shorter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have stored and used pickling liquids in the frige for up to 10 days, and it has been fine.

The guys here

http://www.clemson.edu/extension/hgic/food/food_safety/preservation/hgic3101.html

(Second question down)

State that it is fine as long as you have not used the brine, but to throw if any mould growth occurs (which I think we all probably might do!)

I hope this helps

Comment: I've got the cucumber in the brine already, does that change anything?

Comment: My honest answer is I don't know, but as cucumbers are heavy on water I expect they should be ok.